# Permissions for Dashboards in Azure Devops to see test results

Tags: azure-devops

I am setting up the group of people who should see the test results and dashboards in Azure Devops (for external to project users).

1. I've created another team so they don't see the boards.
2. They have the rights to see the test results and this works, they
   can see the test runs.
3. I've added the Test results dashboard for this new team which works
   fine when you are internal user.

However, external users geting the error "FS.WebApi.Exception: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred." and also no tests data is visible from the dashboard editor. It looks like those external users missing some permissions to see any test data via dashboard but I can't figure out which permissions are missing.

Answer (score 0):

> for external to project users

Are the external users here referring to members of different teams in the same project?

One reason I can think of permission is that the team's **View analytics** permission is set to **deny**,this may cause the widget content to fail to load. You can also view this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/594502/azuredevopsroadmap-returns-http-500-for-dashboards.html) to see if it is the same internal error situation.

[image]